# Script failing to execute more than once

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a chatbot for the web game https://skribbl.io but when my javascript script is run, it only runs once.

```js
function send() {
    var ic = document.getElementById("inputChat");
    ic.value = "ChatBot online";
    ic.parentNode.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {
        bubbles: false,
        cancelable: false,
    }));
}
setInterval(send(), 1000);
```

Comment: Remove () from send() in setInterval **setInterval(send, 1000);** Otherwise you are running the function on load instead of referencing the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval(send, 1000);`
or
`setInterval(() => { send() }, 1000);`

Comment: Unsure of whether I should mark this as the answer because @imvain2 answered first but in comments.

Comment: Their loss if it's not an answer ;)